# Java code with multiplication not working: only displays error message

Tags: java

```
  class DecisionControl1{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        String op = args[1];
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        if(op.equals("*")){
            System.out.println(num1 * num2);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }
}
```

There are no compilation errors in this code, but when I run the application, it always shows the error message.  It doesn't show the output of multiplication.  What is the problem?

Comment: Are you running the command from a shell that interprets the `*` character as a glob pattern?

Comment: Please show us how you are running the program; i.e. show us the complete command line.  Also tell us what shell you are using.

Comment: I got it to work, 2 * 4, and it displays `8`.

Comment: Well ... yea ... I can make that work or not work ... depending on what shell I use, or whether or not the current directory is empty.   There is nothing wrong with the Java code.

Comment: It's the glob thing, I bet. @WinMinThant `*` is magic on the terminal. Either escape it `java DecisionControl1 5 '*' 2` or use something else. Running `java DecisionControl1 5 * 2` makes bash run `java`, passing to `java` the params `DecisionControl1`, `5`, `DecisionControl1.java`, `DecisionControl1.class`, `every-other-file-in-this-dir`, `5`. Which obviously doesn't work. `*` is expanded to 'every file in this dir'.

Comment: _"it always shows the error message"_ What error message?

Answer (score 1):

To clarify the problem, I've edited your code like this (I've just add a println to show the args):

```
package answer;

import java.util.Arrays;

class MyAnswer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(String.format("arg%d: %s", i, args[i]));
        }
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        String op = args[1];
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        if (op.equals("*")) {
            System.out.println(num1 * num2);
        } else {
            System.out.println("error: " + Arrays.toString(args));
        }
    }
}
```

I've compiled this code with (This command mean compile src/java/main/answer/MyAnswer.java into target/classes directory):

```
javac -d target/classes src/java/main/answer/MyAnswer.java
```

Go to target/classes and run your code with java like:

```
java answer.MyAnswer 2 * 8
```

The result looks like:

[image: ubuntu shell]

But if you've run it like this:

```
java answer.MyAnswer "2" "*" "8"
```

Then, you should have the result as expected.

[image: expected result]

So, in your shell, * is interpreted as a [**glob pattern**](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html).

Comment: I got the answer thankful to you all guys!! I added " " when running with multiply operator in command line like this :   number "*" number